# Set dynamic key and values inside for loop

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, key-value

It seems like a basic thing but i am unable to find where i am going wrong .

I want output in this key value format .

```
[{"10":"bob"},{"20":"Tom"},{"30":"Larry"}]
```

What i am doing -

```
var list = [];
var names = ["Bob","Tom","Larry"];
var ages =  ["10", "20", "30"];
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    list.push({ages[i] : names[i]})
}
```

But i am getting unexpected token error . Kindly guide where i am going wrong ?

Comment: You need to enclose the key in `[]` to impose [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Comment: Why do you want that datastructure? It makes little sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set a dynamic string as a property of an object, you can use square bracket notation (`obj[propVariable]`). So, just store an empty object into a variable (`var item = {}`), and then you can set its property through `item[propVariable]`.

```js
var list = [];
var names = ["Bob","Tom","Larry"];
var ages =  ["10", "20", "30"];
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
  var item = {};
  item[ages[i]] = names[i];
  list.push(item);
}
console.log(list);
```

You can read more about square bracket notation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Answer (score 6):

To create dynamic properties you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) :
Try the following:

```js
var list = [];
var names = ["Bob","Tom","Larry"];
var ages =  ["10", "20", "30"];
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++){
    list.push({[ages[i]] : names[i]})
}
console.log(list);
```

Comment: why downvotes for this answer? it actually works fine.